# Appropriately using go to algorithm in R

Tags: r, goto

I have an algorithm written as follows but I need to write that code into R. I have included the algorithm and the R code. I am not sure if that is represented well enough. To write the R code in the sequential order is not straight forward. I am sorry for not providing all the values of the variables here. I am not sure of the output yet which is the reason I am unable to show the required. It is more of a theoretical question.

**Algorithm**

```
         VBDMAX = (va - VG) * 0.79 * (dep / D) ^ -1.21
         VBOWMAX = -0.7 * VBDMAX
         VBOWX = 0
         '  SKIP BOW IF -10D<X<15D OR OUTSIDE EDGE OF BARGES
         If Y > B / 2 Then GoTo 200
         If X < -10 * D Then GoTo 200
         If X >= 15 * D Then GoTo 200

         VBOWX = X * VBOWMAX / (10 * D) + VBOWMAX
         If X <= 0 Then GoTo 200

         VBOWX = X * (VBDMAX - VBOWMAX) / (5 * D) + VBOWMAX
         If X <= 5 * D Then GoTo 200
         VBOWX = -X * VBDMAX / (10 * D) + 15 * VBDMAX / 10
200      ' end bow
```

**This is the R code that I have written**

```
VBDMAX = (va - VG) * 0.79 * (dep / D) ^ -1.21
    VBOWMAX = -0.7 * VBDMAX
    VBOWX = 0
    #  SKIP BOW IF -10D<X<15D OR OUTSIDE EDGE OF BARGES

    VBOWX <- ifelse ((Y>B/2 | X < -10*D | X>=15*D), 0,X*VBOWMAX/(10*D)+VBOWMAX)

    VBOWX <- ifelse (X<=0 , X * (VBDMAX - VBOWMAX) / (5 * D) + VBOWMAX, 
                     ifelse(x <=5*D, -X * VBDMAX / (10 * D) + 15 * VBDMAX / 10))
```

Comment: Is the original code pre Fortran 77 Fortran? Before Fortran had IF, ELSE, END IF?

Comment: I am not sure which code it was originally written on but the extension was *.bas. Not sure which program was used.

Comment: Some old dialect of BASIC then. I think you are probably on the right track just mapping those old instances of GOTO  to ifelse.

Comment: I'd do some I/O testing for the function with the _testthat_ package for instance (see [details here](adv-r.had.co.nz/Testing.html)). Simply evaluate the original function for a few test inputs so you can verify if you get the same result from R.

Comment: The primary error in your example code is that the second `ifelse` will be executed regardless of the outcome of the first `ifelse`, which is not how the source code flows.  You may need to "nest" the conditionals more deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` constructs but you will need to nest those:

```
VBDMAX = (va - VG) * 0.79 * (dep / D) ^ -1.21
VBOWMAX = -0.7 * VBDMAX
VBOWX = 
    ifelse(Y > B / 2 || X < -10 * D || X >= 15 * D,
        0,
        ifelse(X <= 0,
            X * VBOWX / (10 * D) + VBOWMAX,
            ifelse(X <= 5 * D,
                X * (VBDMAX - VBOWMAX) / (5 * D) + VBOWMAX,
                -X * VBDMAX / (10 * D) + 15 * VBDMAX / 10
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Understanding your question as how to translate "goto" statements to R, there are the following posibilities (if really needed) besides or in adjunction to the (often more appropriate) if/ifelse constructions as you already did:

a) entire code (for severe errors or if problem is solved): `if (condition) stop("explain why...")` or `stopifnot(condition)`

b) from within loops: see `next` and `break`

c) from within function: `if (condition) return()`, stopping the function here

Comment: unfortunately, a) results in an error.  it cannot be used to terminate a correct program without an error.